# Order of execution of Rx Operators

Tags: rx-java

I am trying to figure out the order of executions of Rx operators.

What I know is that, the last one is the create operator, ie. the observable doesn't create until a subscriber is there (cold observable).

So, I written this code to test this behavior:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    test(Schedulers.immediate());
    test(Schedulers.computation());
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    test(Schedulers.from(executor));
    executor.shutdown();
    test(Schedulers.io());
    test(Schedulers.newThread());
    test(Schedulers.trampoline());

}


static void test(Scheduler scheduler) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.printf("-------%s--------\n", scheduler);

    Observable<Integer> create = Observable.create(c -> {
        c.onNext(1);
        c.onCompleted();
        print("CREATE");
    });

    create
    .subscribeOn(scheduler)
    .observeOn(scheduler) .map(e -> { print("MAP"); return e * 2; })
    .observeOn(scheduler) .subscribe(a -> { print("SUBSCRIBE");});

    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200);
}

static synchronized void print(String s) {
    System.out.printf("%s %s\n", s, Thread.currentThread());
}
```

The output (similar for multiple runs)

```
-------rx.internal.schedulers.ImmediateScheduler@45ee12a7--------
MAP Thread[main,5,main]
SUBSCRIBE Thread[main,5,main]
CREATE Thread[main,5,main]
-------rx.internal.schedulers.EventLoopsScheduler@1eb44e46--------
CREATE Thread[RxComputationScheduler-3,5,main]
MAP Thread[RxComputationScheduler-2,5,main]
SUBSCRIBE Thread[RxComputationScheduler-1,5,main]
-------rx.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler@3830f1c0--------
MAP Thread[pool-1-thread-2,5,main]
CREATE Thread[pool-1-thread-3,5,main]
SUBSCRIBE Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]
-------rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler@3fb4f649--------
CREATE Thread[RxIoScheduler-4,5,main]
MAP Thread[RxIoScheduler-3,5,main]
SUBSCRIBE Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]
-------rx.internal.schedulers.NewThreadScheduler@48cf768c--------
MAP Thread[RxNewThreadScheduler-2,5,main]
SUBSCRIBE Thread[RxNewThreadScheduler-1,5,main]
CREATE Thread[RxNewThreadScheduler-3,5,main]
-------rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler@2c13da15--------
MAP Thread[main,5,main]
SUBSCRIBE Thread[main,5,main]
CREATE Thread[main,5,main]
```

It appears both `immediate` and `trampoline` schedulers (both that run on the main thread), executes the right way I expect.

But other schedulers are different (however I am `synchronizing` the method `print`, which means AFAIK I am preventing race conditions to happen to the `std output`).

So, why this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Since you your observable is cold chain not starts until you call subscribe.

When you call subscribe chain is starts and firstly invokes `rx.Observable.OnSubscribe#call` then when you call `rx.Observer#onNext` value is submitted to chain. Because of you specify schedulers calling `map` posted to another thread and main thread have time(or not) to finish executing of `rx.Observable.OnSubscribe#call`.

If you move `print("CREATE")` above `rx.Observer#onNext` sequence will be always CREATE -> MAP -> SUBSCRIBE

In this case MAP always before SUBSCRIBE. CREATE is last if everything runs in one thread else in undefined position. Position is undefined due to thread switching.

**Update according to comments**

> why SUBSCRIBE thread created before MAP thread?

Each operator wrap observable into another and return them.

When you call `subscribe()` invoked `rx.Observable.OnSubscribe#call` from last created observable.

And then process doing back through the stack.

```
rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap#call
rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn#call
rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap#call
rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn#call
...
```

And if you look into `OperatorObserveOn` (code cuted)

```
public final class OperatorObserveOn<T> implements Operator<T, T> {

    public OperatorObserveOn(Scheduler scheduler, boolean delayError, int bufferSize) {
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
        this.delayError = delayError;
        this.bufferSize = (bufferSize > 0) ? bufferSize : RxRingBuffer.SIZE;
    }

    @Override
    public Subscriber<? super T> call(Subscriber<? super T> child) {
        if (scheduler instanceof ImmediateScheduler) {
            // avoid overhead, execute directly
            return child;
        } else if (scheduler instanceof TrampolineScheduler) {
            // avoid overhead, execute directly
            return child;
        } else {
            ObserveOnSubscriber<T> parent = new ObserveOnSubscriber<T>(scheduler, child, delayError, bufferSize);
            parent.init();
            return parent;
        }
    }

    /** Observe through individual queue per observer. */
    static final class ObserveOnSubscriber<T> extends Subscriber<T> implements Action0 {
        public ObserveOnSubscriber(Scheduler scheduler, Subscriber<? super T> child, boolean delayError, int bufferSize) {
            this.child = child;
            this.recursiveScheduler = scheduler.createWorker();
            this.delayError = delayError;
            this.on = NotificationLite.instance();
            int calculatedSize = (bufferSize > 0) ? bufferSize : RxRingBuffer.SIZE;
            // this formula calculates the 75% of the bufferSize, rounded up to the next integer
            this.limit = calculatedSize - (calculatedSize >> 2);
            if (UnsafeAccess.isUnsafeAvailable()) {
                queue = new SpscArrayQueue<Object>(calculatedSize);
            } else {
                queue = new SpscAtomicArrayQueue<Object>(calculatedSize);
            }
            // signal that this is an async operator capable of receiving this many
            request(calculatedSize);
        }
    }
}
```

You can see it `createNewWorker` in `call`.

So each `observeOn` create new worker for execution operators below them in reverse order.

As you can easyly see with `Schedulers.newThread()`

CREATE (3) -> MAP (2) -> SUBSCRIBE (1)

Comment: Regardless of CREATE; So why SUBSCRIBE thread created before MAP thread above?

Comment: I don't see any case where subscribe is before map

Comment: In cases 2, 3, 4, 5 (all but the first and the last), the thread number of `SUBSCRIBE` comes before the thread number of `MAP`; doesn't it means that it is executed before it (actual thread run order is not what I am talking about)

Comment: Misunderstand firstly. It is because of stack of observeOn (LIFO) see rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn#call I think it is hard to explain in comment. Each time you call observeOn it create new Observable and when you call subscribe process turns back

Comment: I think code is better. Start from observeOn and go deeper

Comment: CREATE -> MAP -> SUBSCRIBE. So why for `NewThreadScheduler` and `ExecutorScheduler` the order is different?

Comment: I mean start of execution. If place print("CREATE") at the beginning.

Comment: @PogonetsAnton So you did not answer the original question, but replaced it with your own assumptions.

Comment: First part of question contains explanation why order of prints is undefined. Second part why thread for subscribe created before thread for map.

Answer (score 0):

`immediate` and `trampoline` schedulers use current (single) thread so the order of execution is strictly defined.

All other schedulers are multi-threaded. You schedule three tasks to three different threads.

MAP shall always come before SUBSCRIBE because SUBSCRIBE is only scheduled after MAP completes (the result of map() is passed to subscriber).

Apart from that there is absolutely no guarantee in what order the tasks get serialized (by your `print` function).

Comment: Thanks; I just noted that the threads created in this order :(subscribe, map, create) - based in the thread number. But should it be map susbscibe create as in the main thread case?

Comment: @MuhammadHewedy It does not matter in which order threads get created. There is no guarantee of particular order anyway. That's the nature of multi-treading. Do you receive same results (same order for all schedulers) every time you run your program? Try and check it 5-10 times.